# Passing a swift function as a parameter in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a swift class, `A`, which accepts delegates. I have another swift class, `B`, which implements the delegates. Now the object of `A` is instantiated from objective-c code.

**I need to pass the `function g` as a parameter to the `function f`. How do I do this ?**

Class which accepts a delegate :

```
class A {
    func f(_ e: String, d D: @escaping ((String)->Void)) {
        D() // Call the function that we recieved as a parameter
    }
}
```

Class which implements the delegate :

```
class B {
    func g(_ m: String) {
        // Implementation.
    }
}
```

How things are called from obj-c :

```
A *a;
B *b;

[a f:@"someString" d:b.g] // How to pass the swift function as a parameter ?
```

Comment: It looks like closure and it will be treat as block in Obj c

Comment: You need just pass block that calls b's g.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I don't know how to do that. I am a newbie in swift and obj-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate the call to `g` into a Objective-C block like this:

```
[a f:@"someString" d:^(NSString *s) {
    [b g:s];
}];
```

If you also want keeping the parameter function for `d` variable, you need a dictionary of closures:

```
A *a = ...;
B *b = ...;
NSDictionary *myFunctions = @{
    'g': ^(NSString *s) { [b g:s]; },
    'h': ^(NSString *s) { [b h:s]; }
};
NSString *functionName = ...;

[a f:@"someString" d:myFunctions[functionName]];
```

Comment: I am not trying to call `g`. I am trying to pass the function `g` as a parameter to `f`.

Comment: Yes, I understood this but you can't create a Swift-like function from an Objective-C method directly. The closure eliminates this problem. My code doesn't call `g`. It creates a closure to call `g`.